# Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (0, 0): [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLDivElement]]

Tags: c#, jquery, html, selenium-webdriver

> I am trying to move cursor down with below code but getting error stating 
>   Referral.PropertyDetail.propertyDetail:
>   System.InvalidOperationException : Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (0, 0): [object 
>   XrayWrapper [object HTMLDivElement]] (34)
>   Below code i am using to move cursor down

```
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("start-a-referral")).Click();
 driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
 Thread.Sleep(5000);
 IWebElement draggablePartOfScrollbar =    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='slimScrollBar']"));        
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 builder.MoveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).ClickAndHold().MoveByOffset(0,-100).Release().Perform();
```

> Below is the HTML code for scroll bar

```
<div class="slimScrollBar" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 15px; position: absolute; top: 174px; opacity: 0.4; display: block; border-radius: 7px; z-index: 99; right: 1px; height: 113.456px;"></div>
```

> But getting error 
>   Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (0, 0): [object XrayWrapper [object
>   HTMLDivElement]]

Comment: can anyone have the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this question, as it's on the top of google results for this error and I was having similar issue.

I found 4 possible solutions:

1) Maximize the browser window.

2) Turn ON (or OFF) native events.

3) Use CSS selector instead of XPath. - Either [@class='slimScrollBar'] or .slimScrollBar should work. For more information on that, see - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4403

4) Wait for element to load completely... I was looking for an element that was present but not displayed yet.

I see that you tried the first solution already, how about no. 2 and 3?